# vuejs: vue-cli 5 webpack cannot resolve url() in css

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, webpack-5, vue-cli-5

I put the images in public directory(which contains index.html) and I use url() to make a background just like:

```css
.login-container {
  background-image: url('/static/image1.png'),url('/static/image2.png');
}
```

but the vue-cli5 say that
 `Can't resolve '/static/images/login_bg.jpg' in '...\views\login'`

How could I solve this problem? when I use vue-cli 4 it works.